# Which data type in scala/slick matches the geopoint in mysql?

Tags: mysql, scala, geospatial, slick, point

The question is pretty simple. Basically I have a table which has a column of type POINT. When creating the type mapping in slick, which class should I use to map that column type?

Answer (score 0):

These are not currently supported with an existing mapping. See [the section in the manual](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/schemas.html#table-rows) for the list of currently-supported types.

You could try following [the instructions on creating a custom mapping](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/userdefined.html#using-custom-scalar-types-in-queries), but I'm not really sure how to go about it given that there isn't a JDBC class for `POINT`.